# Local storage showing wrong data

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm creating a javascript based code quiz and I want to be able to save the user's finished time and initials in local storage. The initials are showing in local storage and a number is showing, but the number that is shown isn't the stopped time interval. [please view the red circles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C12PQ.jpg) If I need to provide the HTML file, I will. Thanks!

**js file**

```
function answerClick() {
    console.log(this.value)
    //    if function saying if the answer is incorrect
    if (this.value !== myQuestionsArrofObj[currentIndex].answer) {
        secondsLeft = secondsLeft - 15
        //time will be substracted
        //create another if statement, if time <= 0. Then take you to the submit page
        //display "incorrect"
    }


    currentIndex++;
   
    if(currentIndex === myQuestionsArrofObj.length){
        console.log('end game')

        questionContain.setAttribute("style", "display: none !important");
        highscoreContain.setAttribute("style", "display: block !important");
        clearInterval(timeInterval)
       localStorage.setItem("secondsLeft", secondsLeft)

    }else{

        writeQuestion()
    }
}


submitBtn.addEventListener("click", function (event){
    event.preventDefault()

    var leaderNameInput = document.querySelector(".leaderName").value.trim()

    var i = leaderNameInput.value

    var mostRecentScore = {
        leaderName: i,
        score: secondsLeft
    }


    var highscoreArr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("highscoreArr"))|| [];
    highscoreArr.push(mostRecentScore)
     
    if(leaderNameInput ==! " "){
        alert("error, intials must be typed")
    }else{
        window.location.href = "highscore.html"
        localStorage.setItem("leaderNameInput", JSON.stringify(leaderNameInput))
    }
    
    highscoreContain.setAttribute("style", "display: block !important");
    
    
});
```

Comment: You're redirecting before setting the data in the local storage.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more?

Comment: You're aware where your code does a redirection? When that happens, the page is left immediately, nothing will be executed after redirection.

Answer (score 0):

**Updating my answer** 
I think it's logical to have this result because you already have a condition to change that time by - 15

Comment: So the initials are appearing in local storage. But, my problem was that the time wasn't showing correctly. The stopped time would be 11 seconds, in local storage, it would show as -5. Please view the updated screenshot above. Thanks!

Comment: @oksimone I think it's normal because you already make a condition to reduce the time by 15  `  secondsLeft = secondsLeft - 15 `

Comment: okay, I see what you're saying. I thought I had it conditioned to reduce the time if the user guessed the answer incorrectly. I didn't think it would reduce the time another 15 seconds in local storage

Comment: is there any other question or something I can help you with?

Comment: Is there a way to show the correct 'secondsLeft' in local storage? I have that condition where it is because if the user makes the wrong guess, 15 seconds is deducted from the time.

Comment: Should I make a separate function for the local storage items?

Comment: first of all what's the purpose of saving secondsLeft in local storage?

Comment: is all the questions you show to the user are in the same page?

Comment: I want to save the secondsLeft and the initials in local storage so that I can have that data to be saved and shown on another page.

Comment: as the secondsLeft is a time value I mean each second he should to reduce a second by himself, What I suggest is to save DateTime of the start of the quiz in localstorage and in the other pages you make a the diff between the the date initial and date now and how it's should left

Comment: and for the condition if the answer is wrong you can set in localstorage as an increment value, each wrong answer you increment the value of IsWrong in localstorage and in the other pages you make a listener if the value change to 1 for example they reduce the time left till it equals 0 ...

Comment: for the listener here is an example : [link](https://gist.github.com/tomasperezv/5175807)

Comment: I appreciate the help, it's a little difficult to fully explain what I'm trying to do without giving you the entire code. I'll take your suggestion into consideration. Thank you for your time and your amazing help.